# Construct 2 to Windows Phone 8 screen resolution

Tags: windows-phone-8, construct-2

I'm making an app using Construct 2 for Windows Phone 8 and I'm using the screen resolution guidelines found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). I'm using the WXGA screen, so a 768 x 1280 resolution. That is what I have set my layout size to in Construct.

However, when I deploy my app to my device (720 screen) or a WXGA emulator, it seems that the app gets scaled down and there is a black area under my app, like my app isn't using the full screen size. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: For this kind of questions, you should *really* provide screenshots, besides from your code. (And you should always post some code, as it's obviously the culprit of your problem).

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself. Your phone is 720p (16:9), but you're using a WXGA (15:9) resolution.

As described on your link, [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), 720p is ~80 pixels taller.

Also, FYI:

- Lumia 920: **WXGA**
- Samsung ATIV S and ATIV Odyssey: **720p**
- HTC 8X: **720p**